# jQuery validate decimal separator and Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The new Asp.net mvc 2.0 input validation works like a charm, except for decimal separators when it comes to jquery.validate. When I use the Microsoft MVC ajax libs it works fine. The comma is the decimal separator server side as well as client side.

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I use this (jquery is loaded in the master view), I have to use a dot on the client side. But then the model is invalid and it gets returned back to the view, creating an interesting loop.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcJqueryValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'd rather use jquery for all my javascript needs, is there any way to make jquery.validate use the comma, and not the dot ? I have been googling and reading the docs, but weird enough I couldn't find much on this issue, which you would think would be a common one.

Comment: I think a  good way is to post this problem on the blog of scottgu too. He postet on validation a couple of days ago and is fast to answer in the first days of the post.

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh... The joys of globalization!

When dealing with number (and I won't even get started on dates) the need to determine the right decimal separator can be daunting. However, there's an easy way to determine the decimal separator for any client:

```
function GetDecimalSeparator()
{
  return  (1 / 10).ToString().substring(1, 1);
}
```

This way you'll always know what's the decimal separator at the client, and have the validation performed accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how do I get jquery.validate to use this seperator ? And what if it's a dot and the MVC server side expects a comma ? This is getting very confusing ;).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will find the answer in the [additional-methods.js](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js). You will find the example of date localization: search for `<input name="pippo" class="{dateITA:true}" />` and `jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateITA",` which follows. You can do the same to add and use your custom validation of numbers (corresponds to the locale which you use).

Answer (score 0):

You can add *comma* to the regular expresion next to the *dot* in the file jquery.validate.min.js or jquery.validate.js.
In the next example it's mark by bold font. (\. -> [\.,])

```
number: function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:**[\\.,]**\d+)?$/.test(value);
        },
```

Be carefully this original exppresion accept number with thousand separator (,). It wil be better, use RE without thousand separator if you want use *comma* decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to patch jquery validate, although you shouldn't edit the file directly, as Petr suggested, as these modifications will be overwritten if ever you update further down the road.  Here is a better solution : http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2011/03/02/jQuery_validate_and_the_comma_decimal_separator

As a quick fix you could disable client validation, either locally or globally as described here : http://www.campusmvp.net/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-coma-in-decimals/